# Spring Data repository scanning in different maven modules

Tags: spring-data

Is it possible to get Sping Data to scan separate modules for repositories.
I have created a repository in one maven module and wish to access it from another on which it has a dependency.
However I cannot figure out the configuration to tell it to scan in multiple modules/jar files.

In the logs I am seeing multiple references to scanning "core-engine", where the repository that I require is sitting in "test-model"

```
DEBUG main - core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Searching directory
[<path>\engine\core-engine\target\test-classes\] for files matching pattern
[<path>/engine/core-engine/target/test-classes/**/model/repository/**/*.class]
```

The project has a number of modules but there are only 2 that should have an impact in this case and they are "core-engine" and "test-model".
"test-model" contains all of the configuration i.e. the repository definitions, the entities and the repository interfaces.
"core-engine" has a dependency on "test-model".
I am using SpringRunner to run my tests and have tried referring to the ContextConfiguration in "test-model" itself or indirectly by importing the repository config xml into a separate "core-engine" config to no avail. 
I have tests running within the "test-model" module which use the repositories, my problem is just getting access to these repositories from "core-engine".

```
--> test-model (maven module)

---->src/main/java
------>com.test.model.domain (various simple Entities)
------>com.test.model.repository (the repository interfaces)
---->src/main/resources
------>META-INF/datapump/dao-jpa-repository.xml 
---->src/test/java
------>com.test.model.domin (various simple CRUD tests using the repositories) 
---->src/test/resources
------>META-INF/test-context.xml (defines the Application context and imports dao-jpa-respoitory)
```

dao-jpa-repository.xml contains line  which is found and testable within the test-model module

core-engine has a dependency on test-model.

```
--> core-engine (maven module)

---->src/main/java
------>com.test.model.inject (classes which attempt to use the repositories defined in test-model)
---->src/test/java
------>com.test.model.inject (tests for the above classes) 
---->src/test/resources
------>META-INF/test-context.xml (defines the Application context and also imports dao-jpa-respository from the test-model)
```

From above I have a test in the core-engine that tries to persist an entity from the test-model using its repository. However I cannot get access to the repository (through autowiring or by manually looking it up) as it appears that the repository is not in the context.

If anyone could help I'd appreciate it.
Cheers

Comment: Would you mind to briefly outline the project structure? Where are the repository interfaces declared? Where's the XML file containing the `repositories` element? Where is the code located actually bootstrapping the `ApplicationContext` and what dependencies has this module?

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for getting back to me. I have added some extra information under the trace.

Comment: Still hard to get your setup? Would you mind visualising the module structure with some ASCII trees, list packages, show some sample configuration, test cases? Without that there's no way to guess what you're actually setting up there.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity Oliver, I'm trying to focus on the specific parts of the application that are causing the problem. I appreciate your help and hope the additions above showcase my issue.

Comment: Still hard to dig what's wrong without config file contents.